# Parse multi-section file with Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring-batch

I'd like to use Spring Batch to parse the following multi-section file.

1. The headers are listed vertically
2. The number of headers changes from one file to the next
3. There are multiple, distinct "begin/end" tokens
4. Each section (meta, head, data, footer) requires different mappers/tokenizers

Any ideas?

```
START-OF-FILE
PROGRAMNAME=getdata
DATEFORMAT=yyyymmdd

START-OF-FIELDS
ID
NAME
END-OF-FIELDS

TIMESTARTED=Tue May  6 16:17:15 EDT 2014
START-OF-DATA
0|craig|
1|john|
2|tim|
3||
END-OF-DATA
DATARECORDS=4
TIMEFINISHED=Tue May  6 16:49:38 EDT 2014
END-OF-FILE
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to write a custom ItemReader<> that parse every section and return a custom bean: one bean for header and one bean for `START-OF-FIELDS` section as preparation (store this data into step execution context).
About `START-OF-DATA`/`END-OF-DATA` section: data can be parsed with a custom `FlatFileItemReader` (custom because you need to stop on `END-OF-DATA` and not on classic EOF) using header bean gathered before for row mapping.
I hope this can be a good start.